# Incrementing variable in printf()

Tags: c

I was watching a tutorial online and did not fathom why we needed to use this:

```
printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
```

---

So, this is what I have:

```
int k = 6;
k++;

printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k);
```

Output:

```
The value is 7: [ 7]
```

---

Now this is what he did:

```
 int k = 6;
 k++;

 printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
```

Output:

```
The value is 7: [ 7]
```

This one too will print out 7:

```
int k = 6;

printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
printf("The value [%d]\n", k);
```

Output:

```
The value is 7: [ 6]
The value [7]
```

My confusion was what is the importance of incrementing in `printf()` ?

Comment: Moreover if you  write int k = 7;


printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++); you will get the same output! It is very strange...is not it?

Comment: An online tutorial just shouldn't show you kruft like this without putting big warning signs there, really, really explain well what is going on *and* explain why you never should use such code yourself.

Comment: It's really nasty to downvote a question just because the poster is a beginner. This is a genuine question worth asking if the tutorial was confusing.

Comment: I think i got used to that :) haha.

Comment: This post is a bit misnamed since it's about the increment unary operators but I found it looking for printf format strings documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my confusion was what is the importance of incrementing in printf?

There is no importance.

These examples are always only to show people like you how do pre- (`++k`) and post-incrementing (`k++`) operations work. There is no strict rule about incrementing variables inside of `printf()`.

You don't need to do this, but it is very valuable operation, worth knowing.

`++k` is called *pre-incrementation*: value of `k` will be incremented first, then used.
`k++` is called *post-incrementation*: value of `k` will be used first, and then incremented by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Rules:

> 1.when you use `k++` it will increment the k.
>
> 2.when you use for example int b=k++; b will be 6 and k will be 7
>
> 3. when you use int b=++k; the b and k will be 7.

so here in

```
 int k = 6;
 k++;
 printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k);
 return 0;
 }
```

so as a first rule k++   ---> k will be 7 and printf will print 7.

the secod code:

```
int k = 6;
k++;
printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
return 0;
}
```

first rule:k will be 7.

it's like the second rule: the k's value pass to the printf then k will incrementso if you put `printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k);` after that printf it will print 8.

in the third code:

```
 int k = 6;
 printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
 printf("The value [%d]\n", k);
```

here first printf will print 6 because k will pass to it before increment and it's 6 then k will increment and the second printf will print 7.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `k++` returns the value of `k` before the increment, and as a side-effect will increment itself.

So this code:

```
int k = 6;
k++;
printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
```

Will print 7, but `k` will have a value of 8 after the printf line.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `k++` evaluates to the value of `k`. As a side effect, the value of `k` is incremented.

When you use:

```
int k = 6;
k++;
printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k);
```

`printf` will print `7`. The value of `k` after `printf` is still 7.

When you use:

```
int k = 6;
printf("The value is 7: [ %d]\n",k++);
```

`printf` will print `6`. The value of `k` after `printf` is 7.